# Are AWS endpoint overrides universal for all other AWS SDK services?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-flink, amazon-timestream

I'm working on a system that saves large amounts of data to AWS Timestream and AWS S3 from an Apache Flink pipeline. I use the AWS SDK for this.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.89</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

For testing purposes, I'm using a Docker container with [Adobe S3 Mock](https://hub.docker.com/r/adobe/s3mock/) to mock all the data from actually going to AWS S3. I've tried this for Timestream as well, but unfortunately there isn't a mock for that (I think). I'm writing to a real Timestream instance.

To write to the S3 Mock, I've overwritten the endpoint to the Docker container. But, my guess is that the endpoint for Timestream also gets overwritten because they use the same builder.

**Edit:** Both the S3 builder and the Timestream builder extend the `SdkSyncClientBuilder`:

[image]

I'm not 100% sure this is the case, but this is my guess. Disabling the logic for writing to S3 fixes the problem for Timestream. I still want to test locally with the S3 Mock. Below you can find the error message the Timestream SDK provides:

[image: Failed when retrieving a required endpoint from AWS]

Does anyone have any experience with this problem? Or any advice on a better way to test Timestream locally as well?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "my guess is that the endpoint for Timestream also gets overwritten because they use the same builder"? Can you provide example code where they use the same builder? I'm not sure they should use the same builder. In AWS SDK, the S3 client and the Timestream client should be produced using their own builders.

Comment: @Mark Edited the original post

Comment: Although they both extend the same base class I doubt that they both use the same service endpoint. If configured properly they shouldn't as each service has it's own endpoint. You could probably check this using a debugger to inspect the client for each service.

Comment: I would say that as well, but when I remove the S3 sink from the pipeline, data gets inserted into Timestream. When I add the sink back in, I get that exception shown above. So this is my guess on what is happening, but I fully agree with you. The debugger shows the correct endpoints, which makes it even weirder.

Comment: Does the Adobe S3 mock introduce some kind of interceptor that might be re-writing endpoint URLs?